# Working with dbms_lob.copy and error ORA-06502:

Tags: oracle

I am bit lost with working with `dbms_lob.copy`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Ex_PRC IS
 dest_lob CLOB;
 src_lob  CLOB;
BEGIN

  SELECT F_CLOB INTO dest_lob
  FROM EX_EMPLOYEE
  WHERE id = 1;

dbms_lob.copy (dest_lob, src_lob, 30, 1, 1);
  COMMIT;
END;
```

/

I got error 
`numeric or value error invalid lob locator specified ora-22275`

I followed up this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648830/split-blob-file/13680419#13680419) answer because thats what I needed is to split the blob and move them .but I didnt understand why he used  `dbms_lob.createtemporary`

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742687/ora-22275-invalid-lob-locator-specified

Comment: A LOB that is passed to package DBMS_LOB cannot be a variable initialized by EMPTY_CLOB() as this does not create a valid lob locator. 
It must either be initialized by selecting the clob from the database or by using DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY

Comment: @mohsen.b can you provide me an example so i look into it ?

Comment: please look at below examples on scott schema at answer

Comment: posted as answer and delete the comment please @mohsen.b

Comment: create or replace procedure call_clob is
  p_clob clob;
  my_buff varchar2 (2000);
  amt binary_integer := 2000;
begin
  test_clob(p_clob);
  my_buff := dbms_lob.substr(p_clob,amt,1);
  dbms_output.put_line(my_buff);
end call_clob;
/

begin
  call_clob();
end;
/

Answer (score 1):

```
set serveroutput on

create or replace procedure test_clob (p_clob_res out clob) is
  cursor c_tabs is
  select ename from emp;
  v_clob clob;
  amt integer := 0;
begin
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob,true,dbms_lob.session);
  for r_tabs in c_tabs
  loop
    dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob,length(r_tabs.ename)+1,r_tabs.ename||' ');
    amt := amt + length(r_tabs.ename);
  end loop;
  p_clob_res := v_clob;
end test_clob;
/

create or replace procedure call_clob is
  p_clob clob;
  my_buff varchar2 (2000);
  amt binary_integer := 2000;
begin
  test_clob(p_clob);
  my_buff := dbms_lob.substr(p_clob,amt,1);
  dbms_output.put_line(my_buff);
end call_clob;
/

begin
  call_clob();
end;
/
```

Comment: ok thanks you for your example ill test it when i get back to my office